# Alterar a fonte no wordpress.com através do css

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme, css-font-face

Estou tentando mudar a fonte de um site hospedado no WordPress.com. No arquivo `css`, faço a fonte na primeira linha do código:

```
@import "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton";
```

Depois, determino a fonte que será utilizada:

```
font-family: 'Lekton';
```

Na parte de visualização do Wordpress eu consigo ver a mudança de fonte. Porém ao salvar a mudança, ela desaparece. Também tentei usando `@font-face` e não funcionou. O WordPress.com também não permite o upload de arquivos `.eot`, `.woff` e `.svg`.

Comment: Seja bem vindo a comunidade. Você deseja mudar a fonte do tema do seu site, para que as alterações sejam vistas nas páginas, posts, etc?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Desejo alterar o tipo da fonte para Lekton.

Answer (score 1):

Com pouca informação que você passou, vou te pedir para fazer estas alterações e nos comentários você me informa se funcionou ou não.

Altere de:

```
@import "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton";
```

Para:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton';
```

E quando for determinar a fonte, altere de:

```
font-family: 'Lekton';
```

Para:

```
font-family: 'Lekton', sans-serif !important;
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Apresentou comportamento semelhante ao que estava ocorrendo.

Comment: @Raymond qual o link do seu site e qual `class` CSS ou `ID` você está querendo alterar? Assim consigo te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score -1):

Não precisa mudar a sua font via CSS.

Uma possível solução passa por recorrer a um plugin.

Você pode tentar este:

**https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/use-any-font/**

Comment: O problema é que, pelo que eu pesquisei, o WordPress.com ao contrário do WordPress.org não aceita o uso de plugins.